# How to deploy Django using virtual node of apache and virtual python environment?

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, django-wsgi

I have to deploy my Django application on a server which I have limited access to its apache web server. Each student have access to a folder which is a Virtual Host Node with this structure:

```
student/
    cgi-bin/
    html/
    data/
```

Folder data is for files which are not reachable by http. I've created my virtualenv "env" here.
"html" folder is the root document, reachable using http request/responses. For example there's html/index.html which loads when I write my url in the browser. 
Also there's a wsgi file by default here with following directive:
`WSGIScriptAlias /wsgi /home/web/student/html/wsgi.wsgi` 
And finally I've created the django project here. and I don't have permission to write to /etc/apache2/sites-enabled.

So the final structure of student/ is as follow:

```
student/
    cgi-bin/
    html/
        index.html
        wsgi.wsgi
        my_project/
            my_project/
                ...
                wsgi.py
    data/
        env/
```

So I have to modify html/wsgi.wsgi to point to wsgi.py of my django project and also use my virtualenv as python path.

I've modified it as follow:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/web/student/html/my_project/my_project/wsgi.py process-group=my_project
WSGIDaemonProcess my_project python-path=/home/web/student/html/my_project:/home/web/student/data/env/li/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup my_project

<Directory /home/web/student/html/my_project/my_project>
        <Files wsgi.py>
                Require all granted
        </Files>
</Directory>
```

But it still shows that `index.html` as first page, instead of "it worked" page of django.

Comment: You cannot deploy Django in such an environment; out at least you cannot use mod_wsgi to serve it. Get a better host.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I don't have other choices for hosting, since it should be deployed on the university machines. And I'm quite sure that it's possible to run Django since I've been told that it has been done before, but I don't have access to the person who did it.

Comment: this question belongs to the person who maintains the server at your university - you need to know how, when and if the apache gets reloaded on configuration changes that you make in your users folder.

Comment: @dahrens I guessed this as well, because I can not run service apache2 restart. So I don't know how apache would now about changes I've made.

Comment: It's more fundamental than that; mod_wsgi is almost certain not to be installed, and you will have no way of installing it.

Comment: (Also note that the code you posted doesn't go in the wsgi file at all, but in the Apache configuration.)

Comment: What was the contents of ``wsgi.wsgi`` to begin with. All you probably need to do was modify it to set up Python module search path if necessary and have ``from my_project.wsgi import application``.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton it's empty at the beginning. Would you please explain your solution in more details? Because it sounds a little bit confusing and intersting at the same time to me!

Comment: Where is the file located that you claimed had ``WSGIScriptAlias /wsgi /home/web/student/html/wsgi.wsgi`` in it to begin with?